# How do I install memorpy from Githib in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Hello after searching the interwebs for over 1 hour I still can't figure out how to install [memorpy](https://github.com/n1nj4sec/memorpy) from Github to use it in my projects.
I tried putting the folder contained in the .Zip in C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib but when I now try `from memorpy import *`in PyCharm I get the error:

```
    from memorpy import *
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\memorpy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from MemWorker import *
    ImportError: No module named 'MemWorker'
```

What am I doing wrong?
I hope this question finally suits the standard of stackoverflow and doesn't get voted down immediately.

Comment: Anyone? please! this is important